# Flask - POST - The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, post, flask

I just started learning Flask but I meet troubles with the POST method.

Here is my (very simple) Python code :

```
@app.route('/test')
def test(methods=["GET","POST"]):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return('<form action="/test" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></form>')

    elif request.method=='POST':
        return "OK this is a post method"
    else:
        return("ok")
```

when going to :
http://127.0.0.1:5000/test

I successfully can submit my form by clicking on the send button but I a **405 error is returned** :

***Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.***

It is a pretty simple case, but I cannot understand where is my mistake.

Comment: I also tried with action attribute to "" --> same error message

Comment: `methods` goes in the decorator, not the function signature.

Comment: Yes ; more than two hours on this issue... Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You gotta add "POST" in the route declaration accepted methods. You've put it in the function.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method=='GET':
        return('<form action="/test" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></form>')

    elif request.method=='POST':
        return "OK this is a post method"
    else:
        return("ok")
```

See : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/